# How to add new google spreadsheet and update using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Im able to get the spreadsheet data from the below reference
https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js#step_3_run_the_sample

but I didn't found any sample for creating or updating spreadsheet from javascript.

How can I create a new spreadsheet and update it using javascript v4 google API.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Create a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) using Spreadsheet API:

Make an HTTP requests like:

POST `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets`

This POST request comes with a request body. The [request body](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource-spreadsheet) looks something like:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "properties": {
    object(SpreadsheetProperties)
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      object(Sheet)
    }
  ],
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      object(NamedRange)
    }
  ],
}
```

Don't forget to enable the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Try it in the [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Updating Spreadsheets:

You'll be making use of batchUpdate. This method lets you update any of the spreadsheet details. Changes are grouped together in a batch so that if one request fails, none of the other (potentially dependent) changes is written. The batchUpdate method works by taking one or more Request objects, each one specifying a single kind of request to perform. There are many different kinds of requests. Here's a breakdown on the types of requests, grouped into different categories.

More of that in [Updating Spreadsheets docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate).
Format looks like:

```
POST .../v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate
```

Request body:

```
{
  "requests": [{
      "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
          "properties": {"title": "My New Title"},
          "fields": "title"
        }
    }]
}
```

Full [sample here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate#example).